# Rails XHR causes error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5

I am working on a rails app and implementing a form that uploads images. I am using the `XMLHttpRequest` object to submit the form. When I navigate to the page and attempt to submit the form I received the following error: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`.

I've inspected the xhr.responseText and it is empty even though the correct controller action gets hit and renders a json response (I have verified this). If I refresh the page and then try to use the form it works correctly. I'm guessing this might have something to do with turbolinks but I'm not sure. Code below:

**Javascript**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const uploadImage = document.getElementById("upload_image");
  uploadImage.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
    var formData = new FormData(uploadImage);

    event.preventDefault();
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "/upload_image", true);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        const uploadedImage = document.getElementById("uploaded_image");
        uploadedImage.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
        uploadImage.reset();
      }
    };

    xhr.send(formData);
  });
});
```

**Controller**

```
def upload_image
    uploaded_io = params[:file]

    if uploaded_io
      File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', uploaded_io.original_filename), 'wb') do |file|
        file.write(uploaded_io.read)
      end

      render json: "File successfully uploaded: #{File.join(root_url, 'uploads', uploaded_io.original_filename)}", status: 200
    else
      render json: "No file uploaded", status: 400
    end
  end
```

Comment: The problem appears to be that you are sending form encoded data in the body which is just a bunch of key value pairs that looks like `foo=bar&baz=bar` but the request has a JSON content type. Of course that can't be parsed as JSON. You might want to just have a look at ActiveStorage instead of reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was listening for the `DOMContentLoaded` event instead of `turbolinks:load`. This fixed the issue:

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
...
})
```